# Twigで文字列を切り詰めたい(truncate)

Tags: php, twig

PHP、SymfonyでテンプレートにTwigを使っています。

Twigのテンプレートに表示する文字列を、先頭N文字等で切り詰めたいのですが、テンプレート側で使える関数などがあるのでしょうか？

[ドキュメント](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation)を見たところ、truncateというフィルタや関数は標準ではありませんでした。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

単純に文字列を切り詰めるには、Twig 1.6（[2012年2月にリリース](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/releases/tag/v1.6.0)）から導入された [`slice` フィルタ](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html)を使います。

リンク先ドキュメントページにもありますが、使い方は、次のようになります。

```
{{ '12345'|slice(1, 2) }}
```

`|slice()` の部分は `[]` で短く書くこともできます。`companyName` 変数に格納された文字列を先頭から5文字に切り詰める場合は、

```
{{ companyName[:5] }}
```

と書けます。

上記とは違って、切り詰めた場合には「...」を付加するといったことまで含めたtruncateを利用したい場合は、[Twig Extensions](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig-extensions)を導入すれば `truncate` フィルタを使えます。